# Limiting request to an action in Rails controller 3X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

i was wondering whether is it possible to limit the number of request in rails.I tried to impplement this(**WITHOUT DB**),but unable to use instance variable so that a user can only call an action only 5 fimes.I need this to show empty forms that the user can use to fill-in and add more details but only **FIVE** forms.So is it possible without using DB and implement `Add more data` or something limiting to only 5 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Yes. But not without a data store.

You have a couple of options here:

1. Session (client side)
2. Database (server side)
3. Key/value storage like Redis (server side)
4. ...

Example using sessions

```
class SomeController
  def some_action
    session[:some_action_request_count] ||= 0 
    if session[:some_action_request_count] >= 5
      # cleanup
      # flash messages
      # rendering
    else
      session[:some_action_request_count] += 1
      # do somethign
      # rendering
    end
  end
end
```

Why do you have to use some sort of data storage? Because typically a ruby (web)servers run multiple processes which do not share state. And you are not guaranteed that every requests gets to the same process. So you need to persist the data outside of the running server process. This is the reason, why you cannot use an instance variable: Because a new instance will be created in a separate process for your next request.